# Update a bit type column using case statement returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bit

Here is my question (below will be the answer)

I had a need to update a bit column based on the entry of another column in another table on another database.  So my table structure looked like:

```
DB1.Table1 (
field1 int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
,field2 varchar (50)
,field3 bit

DB2.Table2 (
fieldA int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
,fieldB varchar (50)
,fieldC varchar (50)
```

DB2, Table2, fieldC stored entries as Y or N and I needed to convert this to 1 or 0 in the bit column DB1, Table1, field3

I wrote this code to accomplish this:

```
USE DB1
GO

UPDATE Table1
SET field3 = field3 - (CASE WHEN [fieldC] = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 End)
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN DB2.Table2 ON fieldA = field1
```

I would execute and I would get a message that so many records were updated but when I would check my DB1, Table1, field3 everything was NULL.

I looked at this code for a day and a half.  See below for my answer to this problem.

Comment: Could you also share some data example from Table1 and Table2?

Comment: Data like Table1, Field1 would have 1,2,3,4 and Field 2 would have Tom, George, Susie, Brenda and Field3 would have Y,N,N,Y.  Table2, FieldA would be similar 1,2,3,4 and FieldB would have same names but not necessarily in same order as Table1, Field2 and FieldC would be currently blank waiting for Y and N to change to 0 and 1 based on code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the code at all.  There was no default set for the bit column and I'm finding out that this causes some issues such as this one.  Once I changed the table structure to set a default for the bit column the code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

write bits using boolean logic

```
set field3 = fieldC = 'Y'
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out since it is so elegant in it's directness.  I appreciate the suggestion as I'm fairly new to this side of SQL programming (I worked more in Access which really is a different animal)

Comment: I just tried this and I cannot get fieldC to be recognized.  I tried using an alias but still get multi-part identifier cannot be bound.  Only line I changed was the SET line and I set it to what you have above and then tried to add T2 as alias after INNER JOIN Table2 T2 and then changed fieldC to T2.fieldC and still not working.  Might be because table2 is in another database.